# GeoDjango, distance filter based on database column taking into account the radius of both the seeker and the one he is looking for

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I need to find  objects taking into account the radius of both the seeker and the one he is looking for. How i can do this?

At now i can filter from seeker side:

```py
n_range = Obj.objects.filter(location__distance_lt=(
                       obj.location, Distance(mi=obj.radius)
                    )
                )
```

This is my model:

```py
class Obj(models.Model):
    RADIUS_CHOICES = [
        (1, "1 km round"),
        (2, "2 km round"),
        (3, "3 km round"),
    ]
    radius = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=RADIUS_CHOICES[0][0],
        choices=RADIUS_CHOICES
    )
  location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
```

It is necessary that in the end result there should be only those objects that fall into the radius of the seeker, and at the same time, the seeker must fall into the radius of those whom he seeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

obj = Obj.objects.get(id=1)
in_rande = Obj.objects.filter(
    location__distance_lte=(
        obj.location, D(mi=obj.radius)
    )).annotate(
        distance=Distance('location', profile.location)
    ).values('id', 'distance', 'radius')
relevant_ids = [i['id'] for i in in_rande if i['radius'] > i['distance'].km]
```